# How to setup AngularJS workspace using Node JS as backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am new to AngularJS programming and I need to setup development environment using Node JS and AngularJS for backend and frontend respectively. I have gone through several docs but couldn't get a clear idea about creating a workspace for development.

I am using Vagrant(Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) on top of Windows 10 Pro operating system.

Comment: You can use any good starter kit of your requirement.

Comment: @SandeepPatel Can you please share me the GitHub repo?

Comment: @ HenonoaH please refer this: https://github.com/scotch-io/starter-node-angular            This is very basic so  I would suggest you to learn and explore more apart from this.

Comment: Do you already have vagrant box configured?

Comment: @SandeepPatel Thanks. Let me explore repo. Yes, I have already configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the [Angular Fullstack](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) generator and I think it does a good job of getting a project structure set up.

When starting out it might be easier to think of your Node server and AngularJS client as separate projects. Your Node server is handling the API and AngularJS just happens to be a client that uses the API similar to how a native Android or iOS application might use the API.

If you're doing server side rendering then your Node server and client code is going to be more tightly coupled, but I have not heard of server side rendering being used in conjunction with AngularJS. It's worth noting that Angular (not AngularJS) does support server side rendering.